# Store detected faces from stored videos in AWS Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I want to be get the number of unique and repeat visitors at a store. My input feed is video so I'm using StartFaceSearch https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_StartFaceDetection.html and GetFaceDetection https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_GetFaceDetection.html
My problem here is from what I've seen in the documentation Faces can only be added from images using IndexFaces https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_IndexFaces.html

I want to add detected faces from the video into a collection so when customers visit the store their faces are searched for in the collection and if not found, added to the collection. But if found, the id associated with the face in the collection should be given to the person.

Is there a way to add the results from GetFaceDetection into a collection? If there isn't is there some other way to identify unique and repeat visitors?

Thanks!